Prove $\{ x \in A \mid \exists y \in B : |y| = |x|^2 \}$ is a regular language when $A$ and $B$ are regular languages
I am working on proving that $ C(A, B) $ is a regular language, where $A$ and $B$ are regular languages, and $C(A, B)$ is defined as follows:
$$
C(A, B) = \{ x \in A \mid \exists y \in B : |y| = |x|^2 \}
$$
Initially, I tried to utilize the standard closure properties of regular languages (such as union, intersection, and homomorphism), but I didn't have any success. I also attempted to construct an automaton for $ C(A, B) $, but faced challenges, particularly with checking if there exists a string in $ B $ whose length is the square of the length of $ x $.
Any assistance or insights on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Simultaneously cross-posted to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/54828 and https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/170376 . Please, do not do that.

What's the source where you encountered this problem?

The solution follows from the characterization of unary regular languages as unions of semilinear sets.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/164/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/67690/755.  Since this is your exercise, I'll let you work through the remaining details.

It surprises me that the square root of a semilinear set is necessarily semilinear.

@MJD It shouldn’t. It’s perhaps more obvious if you think of a semilinear set as a union of finitely many sets of the form ${x:x\equiv a\pmod m\land x\ge b}$.
